# PHP echo of multiple variable alignment in html datalist tag

Tags: php, html, css, html-datalist

I have the following HTML data list code which grab two columns of data from the database, but it is not presented in one line. I also want to display the full content after selection, as right now it only presents the ID after you select.

Current presentation:

[image]

```
 <datalist id="client_list"  >
              <?php 
              global $wpdb;
              $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM rdb_Client" );
              foreach ( $result as $print )   {?>
            <option value="<?php echo $print -> client_id?>"><?php echo $print -> client_name?> <?php echo $print -> client_contact_person?> </option>
            
            <?php } ?>
          </datalist>
```

After selection:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that you want the width of the dropdown same as option input?

Comment: I actually wanted a display with candidate ID candidate Name in one line, after the selection, as you can see right now only ID is presented after selection

Comment: Try adding `display: flex;` to the `option` element.

Comment: If you could provide with your CSS then I might be able to help.